# UB on a print statement with postfix/prefix?

Tags: c

When I run the following code:

```
int x=2,y=3;
printf("x:%d, y:%d, x*y++:%d, x:%d, y:%d\n", x, y, x*y++, x, y);

x=2; y=3;
printf("x:%d, y:%d, x*++y:%d, x:%d, y:%d\n", x, y, x*++y, x, y);
```

I get the expected result (that is, what I'm personally expecting, not knowing much C):

```
x:2, y:3, x*y++:6, x:2, y:4
x:2, y:3, x*++y:8, x:2, y:4
```

But I also get a warning:

> warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'y' [-Wunsequenced]

Why does the above produce a warning? My thought is that the `printf` function would return `y=2` before the increment is done, and then `y=4` afterwards. The results show that that is the case (at least using GCC on Mac), but why does this produce a warning?